# Issue with colorama module causing entire ASCII art to turn white in Python

Tags: python, colorama

Heyo! I'm trying to create a cool Python program with an ASCII art. However, I'm facing an issue where the specific text I want in white is making the entire ASCII art and everything below it white. I want only the text beside the ASCII art to be white while the rest remains the same color. Here's the code I have so far:

Please note that all the required libraries are already installed, and I'm just showing a portion of the code.

```py
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style, init

init(autoreset=True)

def menu():
    print(f'''
{Fore.CYAN}
           ___          
          /   \\        
      /\\ | . . \\       
    ////\\|     ||       
  ////   \\ ___//\       
 ///      \\      \      
///       |\\      |     
//         | \\  \   \    
/          |  \\  \   \   {Fore.WHITE}Karma
         |   \\ /   /   {Fore.WHITE}- Keys
         |    \/   /    
         |     \\/|     
         |      \\|     
         |       \\     
         |        |     
         |_________\\     

Choose Your Option:
[ 01 ]
[ 02 ]
[ 03 ]

{Style.RESET_ALL}
''')

    command = input("[ Option ] ")

menu()
```

Comment: So you're expecting the white color to just magically end at some point, and go back to cyan?  How is Colorama supposed to know where that point is?  You need to be just as explicit about where cyan starts, as where white starts.